# Aplicativo com Navigation Drawer, Tabs e Fragments

Tags: android

Fiz um aplicativo com Navigation Drawer fazendo uso do assistente do AS, na primeira tela "MainActivity" implementei um layout com TabsLayout e ViewPager e tudo esta funcionando perfeitamente, este app tem outras atividades e estas não tem acesso ao Drawer, só que o solicitante do aplicativo me solicitou isto, pensei em ir fazendo copia em todas as outras atividades para chegar a esta implementação mais mesmo com poucas atividades 6 isto daria um certo trabalho bem "repetitivo", então pensei em usar Fragments.

Com Fragments o meu trabalho seria reduzido visto que o "miolo" da tela é que seria atualizado e isto reduziria o meu trabalho de ter quer sair inserindo o drawer em todas as outras atividades mais...., estou encontrando dificuldades para usar Fragments e refatorar o meu app o que me veio então a questão é uma boa pratica ter um aplicativo com estes recursos? a própria IDE nos seus assistentes ou dá opção de um ou de outro, procurei por exemplos com Drawer e Tabs ou por algum post que aborde o assunto, encontro Drawer e Fragments mais ainda dentro disto com Tabs não.

Até consegui nesta minha primeira atividade colocar em um fragment só que já encontrei problemas com o Tabs que não ficou junto com a Toobar, se eu rotaciono o dispositivo o conteúdo da Tabs desaparece, então apos eu selecionar uma ou outra que a mesma aparece, então estou até com receio de partir para as outras atividades transformando-as em fragments.

Sera que é uma boa pratica um aplicativo com estes elementos?

Comment: Interessado em boa práticas?! Veja isso: https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Comment: O que ser 'assistente do AE'?

Comment: Olá Ack Lay boa tarde, prezado desculpe fiz a correção é AS - Android Studio

Answer (score -2):

Olá, uso tabs com fragments numa boa, a questão da rotação é porquê o android destroi a sua activity e recria na nova orientação, isso pode ser contornado, vou deixar uns links abaixo que vão ajudar:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/
https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a

Sobre a questão da orientação, uma maneira simples de resolver é informar para o android que você não quer que sua activity seja recriada após a rotação. Basta colocar o código abaixo no AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
android:name="meu.pacote.MinhaActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Olá Fernando concordo que tabs e fragments é tranquilo, mais adicionar a isso o Navigaton Drawer e manter ele para qualquer atividade ou novo fragmento chamado do Drawer esse é o caso que tenho que resolver.